# Browser download images from srcset and original image

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, retina

For example i have such `img`:

```
<img src="images/image-520.jpg"
     alt="some image"
     srcset="images/image-1040.jpg 2x"
>
```

On normal, not retina displays, browser only download `image-520.jpg` but on retina displays, both chrome desktop and safari for iOS at first download and render `image-1040.jpg` and after `DOMContentLoaded` event, they download original `image-520.jpg` image. Can anyone explain why this happens, and how to avoid this?

Comment: Are you using picturefill here?